# How to set the text colour on a button? JAVA

Tags: java, swing, button

how do you set the text colour on a button. I have tried this but it is not working.

```
  JButton button1 = new JButton();
    button1.setForeground(Color.RED);
    button1.setText("Close");
    button1.setEnabled(false);
```

The colour stays black.

Comment: It should work. Show more code.

Comment: A disabled button is grayed out.  You have to enable the button to see the color.

Comment: dark grey, I think it was because the button is disabled, when I enabled the button it worked, is it possible to change the color when the button is disabled because I need the button to be disabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to change the color when the button is disabled

You may be able to use the UIManager for this. See [UIManager Defaults](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) for more information.

If you can use the UIManager, then you will need to create a custom UI.

Comment: having a look at the link you gave, I think I may be able to use it but it will add extra code, therefore I will stick with no disabling the button and only having the text colour to change.